# How to make click action on button using tapestry page tester

Tags: tapestry

I'm writing some tests for tapestry application. PageTester gives a clickLink method which  simulates a click on a link. I need the same functionality, but with the button (not with 'a' element). How could I possibly achive it ?

Code sample,
This is what I know how to do:

```
@Test
public void clickLink(){

    Document document = pageTester.renderPage("Index");

    assertTextPresent(document, "Current value:0");

    Element link = document.getRootElement()
            .getElement(new Predicate<Element>() {
                public boolean accept(Element element) {
                    return element.getName().equals("a")
                            && element.getChildMarkup().equals("Increment");
                }
            });

    document = pageTester.clickLink(link);

    assertTextPresent(document, "Current value:1");

    document = pageTester.clickLink(link);

    assertTextPresent(document, "Current value:2");
}
```

But the problem is that clickLink accept only 'a' element.
So how can I get the same functionality, but when I have button, which make some aciton (not link).

Comment: Is it possible to post your code?

Comment: Is the button a form submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [tapestry documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/unit-testing-pages-or-components.html) states - "The PageTester falls into a middle ground between pure unit testing and full-scale integration testing."

The PageTester is a java only simulation which can simulate:

1. Clicking on a `<t:eventlink>`
2. Clicking on a `<t:actionlink>`
3. Submitting a `<t:form>`
4. Clicking on a `<t:submit>`

If you created a `<button>` and attached an `onclick` javascript handler, the PageTester can not simulate this since it does not actually run any javascript. If you want to test javascript, you will need to use [selenium](http://tapestry.apache.org/integration-testing.html)